# Python3 でインポート先のモジュールが同じフォルダ内のモジュールをインポートできません

Tags: python

```
■フォルダ
|---■実行ファイル.py
|---■\__init__.py
|---■パッケージ
　　|---■\__init__.py
　　|---■モジュール1.py
　　|---■モジュール2.py
```

のような関係で実行ファイルから

```
from パッケージ　import モジュール1
```

とした時、モジュール1の中の

```
import モジュール2
```

の文が上手く行かず

```
ImportError: No module named 'モジュール2'
```

と出てしまい、コンピューターには疎いため困っています。
プログラムはWindows10でSpyderのIPython上で動かしています。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

同じパッケージ内のモジュールをインポートするには`from . import モジュール2`と書きます。

または`from パッケージ import モジュール2`とパッケージ名も指定して書けばインポートできます。

Comment: 解決しましたありがとうございます